# Redundancy in definition for forcing poset

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The following definition appears in Kunen (2nd edition):

For any sets $I,J$ and cardinal $\lambda$: $\text{Fn}_{\lambda}(I,J)$ is the set of all $p\in{[I\times{J}]}^{<\lambda}$ such that $p$ is the graph of a function. We make $\text{Fn}_{\lambda}(I,J)$ in to a forcing poset by letting $\leq$ be $\supseteq$ and $1=\emptyset$.

My question is: Since $p$ is a function to begin with, doesn't this mean that $p$ is also the graph of a function with $p=\{(x,p(x)):x\in{\text{dom}{(p)}}\}$? Or is there something to be gained by (possibly in a different way) regarding $p$ as the graph of a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I conjecture you've confused $[I\times J]^{<\lambda}$, which is the set of $<\lambda$-sized subsets of $I\times J$, with $(I\times J)^{<\lambda}$, which is a set of functions.

Comment: This rather specialized use of square brackets is unfortunate but standard. Some people write $\mathcal P_{<\lambda}(I\times J)$ or $\mathcal P_{\lambda}(I\times J)$ instead.

Comment: That is exactly what it was and now I feel stupid about missing it. Thank you.

Comment: In the 1st edition, Kunen uses $Fn(I,J,\lambda)$ for $Fn_{\lambda}(I,J).$